# Action script 3.0 onSwipe{ gotoAndPlay(x); {

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Action script 3.0

swipe left/down/right/up gotoAndStop/play (x)?? Someone got a skeleton code of this? I know how to make it in Air for ios/android, but not on regular 3.0. Thanks.

Comment: What is "regular 3.0"? Is there an irregular one, too? :)

Comment: Haha, veru funny sir :). No, there are no irregular actionscript3.0, but I cant use the mobile air codes on the actionscript 3.0 project that arent for mobiles ;) That is what i meant..

Comment: Of course you can. There are touch screens for desktop as well. But as far as I understand it you want to create the same "swipe" gesture with mouse, correct? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking in general - you're not showing specific code:

Use MouseEvents in place of TouchEvents - mousedown in place of a touchBegin for example.  mouseX for the position, mouseMove event for swipe code, etc.

Unless you're handling gestures, it should be pretty easy to swap.